# Using differentials to find an approximate formula for percentage increase

Tags: partial-derivative, volume

I have some past exams that I'm practicing before the real thing. They didn't come with answers and I'm really stumped on this one question:

"The volume *V* of a cylinder of radius *r* and height *h* is given by $V=\pi r^2 h$. Using differentials, find an approximate formula for the percentage increase in *V* in terms of the percentage increase in *r* and *h*. That is, find an approximate formula for $\frac {δV}{V}$ in terms of $\frac {δr}{r}$ and $\frac {δh}{h}$."

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Take the logarithm of both sides and differentiate wrt $r$ and $h$ and you will get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For fixed $h$ we have:

$\delta V=\dfrac{\partial V}{\partial r} \delta r=2\pi hr$ , so $\dfrac{\delta V}{V}=\dfrac{2\pi h r \delta r}{\pi r^2 h}=2\dfrac{\delta r}{r} $.

For fixed  $r$:

$\delta V=\dfrac{\partial V}{\partial h} \delta h$ and: $\dfrac{\delta V}{V}=\dfrac{\pi r^2 \delta h}{\pi r^2 h}=\dfrac{\delta h}{h} $.

Comment: Could I ask how you knew that δV=(∂V/∂r)δr and δV=(∂V/∂h)δh were the way to go about it?

Comment: I've used your notation, but $ \delta$ is simply the differential.